# What are the Steam Community Market fees for Dota, TF2, & CS:GO?

Tags: steam-community-market

[Reference](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6088-UDXM-7214)

When I sell something in the Steam Community Market, there's a "Steam Fee" of 5%, but there are also "game-specific fees" for Dota2/CSGO/TF2 (each at 10%).

Are those fees additive? For example, if I sell an item for CS:GO, is the total transaction fee 10%, or 15% (10% game-specific fee + 5% Steam fee)?

Also, what verification documents does Steam require for big sellers?

Comment: I'm confused too. What exactly are you asking us here?

Answer (score 10):

You're probably confusing with how the [Steam Market](http://steamcommunity.com/market) works.

> There is a "Steam Fee" which is 5%, but there are also "game specific fees" for Dota2/CSGO/TF2 (each at 10%).

When you sell an item on the market, you're asked for two values: "Buyer pays" and "You receive", which are relative to each other. (As in: Changing one box will change the other).

This means that every time you sell an item on the market, Valve and the creators of the game (in this case; Grinding Gear Games, for Path of Exile) will get a cut of the profits you received when selling the item.

For example, if I was to sell a Path of Exile mask for $10.00, I would receive $8.50 (my cut of 85%), Valve would receive $0.50 (5% cut) while the creator of the game; Grinding Gear Games will receive $1.00 (10% cut), while the buyer has to pay all $10.00 of it.

CS:GO/TF2/DoTA 2/Portal/Steam items would result in Valve receiving a 15% cut (5% from standard tax and 10% from owning the game) etc.

> Also, what verification documents does Steam require for big sellers?

When you hit 200 market transactions (or $20,000 USD worth), whichever happens first, you'll be blocked from using the market further until you fill up a tax information form. For non-US customers, this shouldn't be a problem, as you **will not be charged extra tax**.

For those who live in the US however (and exceeding the $20,000 USD threshold), income will be reported to the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/understanding-your-form-1099-k) and taxes will have to be paid as income tax, **outside of the Steam Marketplace**. You'll get a 1099-K.

Comment: Sorry to bump a 2 year old question, but I think there's some slight difference. When you list an item for `10€` what shows up automatically in the "you get" box is `8.7€` and not `8.5` as would be expected from a 15% tax. I think there is some slight difference somewhere, where sometimes a 13% tax is applicable and others a 15%

Comment: @Sosi It could be algorithm that does the calculations (from one to the other and backwards) that's causing this. Also, it's only 5 months old :/

Comment: right! I found out what my issue in these calculations was. I was computing `10*0.85` but it should've been `10/1.15`. All is straighten up after all

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The seller's profit **does not get cut**.  As stated in the Community Market FAQ (https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6088-UDXM-7214), **the buyer pays the Steam Transaction Fee**.  As @Sosi pointed out, you _appear_ receive 86.96% of your listed price.  In reality, the buyer pays the seller's income **plus** 15% in fees - it's not a penalty on the seller.

Comment: @scriptHero Feel free to edit the answer and I'll accept the changes (if you're below 2k Rep)

Comment: @aytimothy Apologies for bump on a year-old answer.  I've submitted my edit.

Comment: @scriptHero Apologies; [I rejected your edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/178232) on the grounds of it being too drastic, but didn't realise the original author was okay with it. If you get this kind of permission please do put it in the edit comment; I cannot by default see comments in the Suggested Edit queue. I'm sure you'd be welcome to submit your changes again; alternatively, ping me and I'd be glad to make the edit for you (though you'll miss the +2 rep).

Answer (score 0):

> There is a "Steam Fee" which is 5%, but there are also "game-specific fees" for Dota2 / CSGO / TF2 (each at 10%).

[image]

When you sell an item on the market, you get a dialog with 2 inputs: "You receive" and "Buyer pays", which are dependent of each other.

Every time you sell an item on the market, you will receive the amount you put in the "You receive" box from a buyer. The buyer will pay an additional amount - 5% to Steam, and another fee to the game developer (10% for Dota 2, CS:GO, and TF2).

For example, if I listed a Golden Frying Pan for $10, the buyer would pay $11.50 split like so:

```
Seller:   $10
Steam:    $0.50 (5%)
Valve:    $1    (10%)
```

---

> Also, what verification documents does Steam require for big sellers?

When you reach 200 market transactions (or $200 USD worth), whichever happens first, you'll be blocked from using the market further until you fill up a tax information form. For US users, this will also result in being charged a tax - part of your earnings will be cut as part of income taxes.

Answer (score 0):

For US tax its (Buying price)*0.1303 and you get your amount of money taken away so you do (Buying price)-(Amount taken away) if that doesnt make sense, you do 123*0.1303= 16.0269 than you do 123-16.0269=106.9731(the amount you get from selling it)

Comment: I'm confused, where are you getting 0.1303 from?